# Form button CSS styling only works in inspect

Tags: html, css, forms

So, I want to style this:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" class="submit-btn">
```

I'm using this to do so:

```
.submit-btn {
 height: 41px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: white;
 top: -3px;
}
```

```css
.submit-btn {
 height: 41px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: white;
 top: -3px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" class="submit-btn">
```

However, it doesn't respond to my styling. It only responds the moment I left click and do "Inspect Source".

Comment: Please share page link

Comment: https://codepen.io/dario-sanchez-martinez/pen/rqjKMb

Comment: The style is reflecting, what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I do not see the style, you see the style even in the snippet?

Comment: What is problem here? because style is applied

Comment: In Chrome, I see the button as unstyled unless a background colour other than white is added. Adding a border also seems to work.

Comment: If you don't need the style, remove class ="submit-btn" from html

Comment: The problem is that I do not see the style applied!

I'm on google chrome, Mac computer.

Comment: Thanks @Turnip, works now!